# Magento 2: SQL error when redeeming coupon code

Tags: magento2, coupon, sales-rule

Magento 2.2.9

When I try to redeem a coupon code I get an SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rule_coupons.expiration_date' in 'where clause', query was: 
SELECT `t`.*
FROM (
SELECT `main_table`.*, NULL AS `code`
FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT `salesrule_website`.`rule_id`
FROM `salesrule_website`
WHERE (website_id IN (1))) AS `website` ON main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id
INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids` ON main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = 1
WHERE (from_date IS NULL OR from_date <= '2019-11-13') AND (to_date IS NULL OR to_date >= '2019-11-13') AND (`is_active` = '1') AND (main_table.coupon_type = 1) UNION ALL
SELECT `main_table`.*, `rule_coupons`.`code`
FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT `salesrule_website`.`rule_id`
FROM `salesrule_website`
WHERE (website_id IN (1))) AS `website` ON main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id
INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids` ON main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = 1
INNER JOIN `salesrule_coupon` AS `rule_coupons` ON main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND main_table.coupon_type <> 1 AND rule_coupons.code = 'test'
WHERE (from_date IS NULL OR from_date <= '2019-11-13') AND (to_date IS NULL OR to_date >= '2019-11-13') AND (`is_active` = '1') AND ((rule_coupons.expiration_date IS NULL OR rule_coupons.expiration_date >= '2019-11-13') AND (main_table.coupon_type = 3 AND rule_coupons.type = 1 OR (main_table.coupon_type = 2) AND ((main_table.use_auto_generation = 1 AND rule_coupons.type = 1) OR (main_table.use_auto_generation = 0 AND rule_coupons.type = 0))))) AS `t`
WHERE ((rule_coupons.expiration_date IS NULL) AND (to_date IS NULL OR to_date >= '2019-11-13') OR (rule_coupons.expiration_date IS NOT NULL) AND (rule_coupons.expiration_date >= '2019-11-13')) AND ((main_table.to_date IS NULL) OR (main_table.to_date >= '2019-11-13')) AND (`is_active` = '1')
ORDER BY sort_order ASC
```

I checked the table and the column expiration_date definately exists. I removed all existing rules and created only one simple rule that generates a discount.

I cannot wrap my head around. Why does it complain about a missing column that definately exists?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well that error is because you cannot refer the `rule_coupons` table inside the final WHERE of the main select. `rule_coupons` is an Select inside of an inner join, because of that you can not refer `rule_coupons` in the WHERE at the final end.
The same is for `main_table`, because it is an subselect inside of `FROM`, it is scoped to the `FROM` part of your sql statement. You are not able to use `main_table` outside of the `FROM`.
The other way around is possible to use an identifier outside the Subselect from within a Subselect, but it is not possible this way around.

You need to join the `salesrule_coupon` inside your main select, or use some kind of subselect on `salesrule_coupon` to apply this filters to your main select.
The other filters on the main_table can be applied, because you are selecting the according values.

Without the filters on salesrule_coupons the final where could look like this:

```
WHERE 
 ((to_date IS NULL) OR (to_date >= '2019-11-13')) AND (`is_active` = '1')
```

and it would work fine. Remember: still without the filters on salesrule_coupon.

Actually, i am not exactly sure what you are trying to do with this huge select, but i guess there is an easier way for a more understandable select, which will return the same ;)

So maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(
    SELECT sr.*, NULL as `code` FROM salesrule AS sr
    INNER JOIN salesrule_website AS srw ON srw.rule_id=sr.rule_id AND srw.website_id=1
    INNER JOIN salesrule_customer_group AS srcg ON srcg.rule_id=sr.rule_id AND srcg.customer_group_id=1
    WHERE 
    (sr.from_date IS NULL OR sr.from_date <= '2019-11-13') 
    AND (sr.to_date IS NULL OR sr.to_date >= '2019-11-13') 
    AND (sr.`is_active` = '1') 
    AND (sr.coupon_type = 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sr.*, sc.code FROM salesrule AS sr
    INNER JOIN salesrule_website AS srw ON srw.rule_id=sr.rule_id AND srw.website_id=1
    INNER JOIN salesrule_customer_group AS srcg ON srcg.rule_id=sr.rule_id AND srcg.customer_group_id=1
    INNER JOIN salesrule_coupon as sc ON sc.rule_id=sr.rule_id AND sr.coupon_type <> 1 AND sc.code='test'
    WHERE 
    (sr.from_date IS NULL OR sr.from_date <= '2019-11-13')
    AND (sr.to_date IS NULL OR sr.to_date >= '2019-11-13')
    AND (sr.`is_active` = '1')
    AND (
        (sc.expiration_date IS NULL OR sc.expiration_date >= '2019-11-13')
        AND (sr.coupon_type = 3
        AND sc.type = 1 OR (sr.coupon_type = 2)
        AND (
            (sr.use_auto_generation = 1 AND sc.type = 1) 
            OR (sr.use_auto_generation = 0 AND sc.type = 0)
        )
    ))
) AS t
LEFT JOIN salesrule_coupon AS tc ON tc.rule_id=t.rule_id
WHERE 
(
    (tc.expiration_date IS NULL) 
    AND (t.to_date IS NULL OR t.to_date >= '2019-11-13')
    OR (tc.expiration_date IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (tc.expiration_date >= '2019-11-13')
) AND 
(
    (t.to_date IS NULL) 
    OR (t.to_date >= '2019-11-13')
) AND (t.`is_active` = '1')
ORDER BY t.sort_order ASC;
```

Comment: i guess the UNION ALL can be somehow avoided by using a left join in the first subselect. And this way the SELECT( SELECT can be avoided next etc..

Comment: I am not trying to do anything with this. This is just somehow the query magento produces when I try to redeem a coupon code. And it fails due to this query. Now I'm kinda lost where to go from here.

Comment: Do you have some module installed which extends the salesrules ? I'm pretty confused if the Magento2 core really generates invalid SQL statements...

Comment: I disabled all non-magento modules and the error goes away. This will take a while. Will report back when I found the sucker.

Comment: I found that by disabling the module `Dotdigitalgroup_Email` the error disappears.
What confuses me is that I have another store without any problems even with `Dotdigitalgroup_Email` enabled.

Comment: `Dotdigitalgroup_Email` is part of the magento product community metapackage. Maybe some module which depends on this one (module sequence) ?